# Angular2: variable scope inside template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In angular2 parent component, I have the following code, imgs is a private class variable. The below code can let image variable passed to its child component. That's exactly what I want.

However, I am confusing about the scope of image variable. It doesn't have any access modifier like public or private, but it acts like public variable. Can anyone explain how it works?

```
<li *ngFor="let image of imgs">
    <child [image]="image"></child>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [**ngFor**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) documentation page on the Angular 2 site

> **Class Description**
>
> The NgFor directive instantiates a template once per item from an iterable. The context for each instantiated template inherits from the outer context with the given loop variable set to the current item from the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

The image variable only exists within the template, and only within the closing tags of the element `*ngFor` was attached to. It only exists for the child component as the property it was bound to, not the same `image` variable.